# Unrecognized rule error

Tags: lex, flex-lexer

```
    %option lex-compat
    %option noyywrap
    %option yylineno
    %{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    %}
    %{
    int INDENT=0,DEDENT=0,line=0;
    %}
    HASH    "#"
    NEWL    [\n]
    SPACE   " "
    MULTS   """
    COMP    "e^"
    LETTER  ([a-zA-Z])
    HEXL    ([a-fA-F1-9])
    ZERO    "0"
    EXP     "10^"
    COLON   ":"
    DOT     "."
    LPAREN  "("
    RPAREN  ")"
    PLUS    "+"
    MINUS   "-"
    SIGN    ({PLUS}|{MINUS})
    MULT    "*"
    DIV     "/"
    ASSIGN  "="
    EQUAL   "=="
    MORE_THAN ">"
    LESS_THAN "<"
    OR      "or"
    AND     "and"
    NOT     "not"
    IF      "if"
    ELSE    "else"
    LAMBDA  "lambda"
    FOR     "for"
    PASS    "pass"
    H       ({"h"|"H"})
    WHITESPACE  {[\t\n]}
    NUM_NZ      [1-9]
    NUM         [0-9]
    INTEGER     ({SIGN}?({ZERO}|({ZERO}+/({NUM_NZ}+))))
    REAL        ({INTEGER}{DOT}{NUM}|{INTEGER}{DOT}{NUM}{EXP}{INTEGER})
    HEX         ({PLUS}?(ZERO}|{HEXL}+{H}))
    COMPLEX     ({PLUS}?{REAL}+{COMP}{SIGN}?(({REAL}/"i")|"i"))
    ID          ("'"{.}+/{LETTER}+"'")
    STRING      ("'"{.}+"'")
    MULTISTRING ({MULTS}({.}+)|{NEWL}+{MULTS})
    COMMENT     ({.}+/{HASH})
    %%
   {SPACE}      {INDENT++; };
   {NEWL}   
    {
     if(INDENT>DEDENT) printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme:       '%s').\n",yylineno,"INDENT",yytext);  
     if(INDENT<DEDENT)  printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"DEDENT",yytext);   
     DEDENT=INDENT; line++;};
    {INTEGER}       printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"INTEGER",yytext);
   {REAL}           printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"REAL",yytext);
    {HEX}           printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"HEX",yytext);
    {COMPLEX}       printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"COMPLEX",yytext);
    {STRING}        printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"STRING",yytext);
    {MULTISTRING}   printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"MULTISTRING",yytext);
    {IF}            printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"IF",yytext);
    {ELSE}          printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"ELSE",yytext);
    LAMBDA}     printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"LAMBDA",yytext);
    {FOR}           printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"FOR",yytext);
    {PASS}          printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"PASS",yytext);
    {ID}            printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"ID",yytext);
    {COLON}         printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"COLON",yytext);
    {LPAREN}        printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"LPAREN",yytext);
    {RAREN}         printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"RPAREN",yytext);
    {ARITH_OP}      printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"ARITH_OP",yytext);
    {REL_OP}        printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"REL_OP",yytext);
    {LOGIC_OP}      printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"LOGIC_OP",yytext);
    {NOT}           printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"NOT",yytext);
    {ASSIGN}        printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"ASSIGN",yytext);
    .       printf("Line %d: Invalid token  ('%s').\n",yylineno,yytext);
    %%
    int main(int argc,char* argv[])
    {
yylex();
    }
```

I have an unrecognized rule in line 102 which contains  `yylex();`.
What did I do wrong, and where is the error? I cannot find it.

```
hw1.text , line 102: unrecognized rule
```

when I try to compile it, I get this error.
I'm writing `flex hw1.text` and the file and the `flex` are in the same folder.

---

#### Comments added based on deleted non-answer(s)

I did what you told me to do, for some reason I get an error for the 'printf' lines.

I've added :

```
ARITH_OP   ({PLUS}|{MINUS}|{DIV}|{MULT})
REL_OP     ({MORE_THAN}|{LESS_THAN}|{EQUAL})
LOGIC_OP   ({AND}|{OR})
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: You got *what* error?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of problems that I see:

1. The action after `{NEWL}` should start on the same line as `{NEWL}`.

   ```
   {NEWL}
   {
   if(INDENT>DEDENT) printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme:       '%s').\n",yylineno,"INDENT",yytext);
   if(INDENT<DEDENT)  printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"DEDENT",yytext);
   DEDENT=INDENT; line++;};
   ```

   This should be something like:

   ```
   {NEWL} {
             if(INDENT>DEDENT) printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme:       '%s').\n",yylineno,"INDENT",yytext);
             if(INDENT<DEDENT)  printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"DEDENT",yytext);
             DEDENT=INDENT; line++;
          };
   ```
2. Another problem is a missing `{` for the `{LAMBDA}` rule:

   ```
   {ELSE}          printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"ELSE",yytext);
   LAMBDA}     printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"LAMBDA",yytext);
   {FOR}           printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"FOR",yytext);
   ```
3. You use `{RAREN}` instead of `{RPAREN}`.
4. You have not defined `{ARITH_OP}`, `{REL_OP}`, or `{LOGIC_OP}`.
5. I think the rule for MULTS should be something like this (but I might be wrong):

   ```
   MULTS "\""
   ```
6. To get a clean compilation, I moved the following rules into a comment after the rules section of the scanner:

   ```
   {MULTISTRING}   printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"MULTISTRING",yytext);
   {ID}            printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"ID",yytext);
   {STRING}        printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"STRING",yytext);
   {HEX}           printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"HEX",yytext);
   {COMPLEX}       printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"COMPLEX",yytext);
   {INTEGER}       printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"INTEGER",yytext);
   {REAL}          printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"REAL",yytext);
   {ARITH_OP}      printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"ARITH_OP",yytext);
   {REL_OP}        printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"REL_OP",yytext);
   {LOGIC_OP}      printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n",yylineno,"LOGIC_OP",yytext);
   ```

You also, clearly, need a function in place of the repetitive `printf()` statements.

---

#### 'Working' Code

This code compiles and runs.  There are still lots of problems with the rules (for instance, the real numbers can only have a single digit after the decimal point, and identifiers must be enclosed in single quotes).  It uses a `print_token()` function to make the scanner actions readable.

```
%option lex-compat
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno

%{
#include <stdio.h>
/*#include <conio.h>*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
%}

%{
int INDENT=0, DEDENT=0, line=0;
static void print_token(const char *token);

/*
Original rules moved out of the way:

MULTISTRING ({MULTS}({.}+)|{NEWL}+{MULTS})
STRING      ("'"{.}+"'")
INTEGER     ({SIGN}?({ZERO}|({ZERO}+/({NUM_NZ}+))))
ID          ("'"{.}+/{LETTER}+"'")
H           ({"h"|"H"})
COMPLEX     ({PLUS}?{REAL}+{COMP}{SIGN}?(({REAL}/"i")|"i"))
MULTISTRING ({MULTS}({.}+)|{NEWL}+{MULTS})
*/

/*
Examples of patterns matched:

INTEGER: 1 +1 -2 0 99 999 987654321092344
REAL:    1.2 -2.1 3.14159
ID:      'ThisIsAnId'
HEX:     +0 DeadBeefH
*/
%}

HASH        "#"
NEWL        [\n]
SPACE       " "
MULTS       "\""
COMP        "e^"
LETTER      ([a-zA-Z])
HEXL        ([a-fA-F1-9])
ZERO        "0"
EXP         "10^"
COLON       ":"
DOT         "."
LPAREN      "("
RPAREN      ")"
PLUS        "+"
MINUS       "-"
SIGN        ({PLUS}|{MINUS})
MULT        "*"
DIV         "/"
ASSIGN      "="
EQUAL       "=="
MORE_THAN   ">"
LESS_THAN   "<"
OR          "or"
AND         "and"
NOT         "not"
IF          "if"
ELSE        "else"
LAMBDA      "lambda"
FOR         "for"
PASS        "pass"
H           ("h"|"H")
WHITESPACE  {[\t\n]}
NUM_NZ      [1-9]
NUM         [0-9]

INTEGER     ({SIGN}?{NUM_NZ}+)

REAL        ({INTEGER}{DOT}{NUM}|{INTEGER}{DOT}{NUM}{EXP}{INTEGER})
HEX         ({PLUS}?({ZERO}|{HEXL}+{H}))
COMPLEX     ({PLUS}?{REAL}+{COMP}{SIGN}?(({REAL}"i")|"i"))

ID          ("'"{LETTER}+"'")
STRING      ("'"[^']+"'")
MULTISTRING ({MULTS}([^"]+)|{NEWL}+{MULTS})
COMMENT     ({.}+/{HASH})
ARITH_OP    ({PLUS}|{MINUS}|{DIV}|{MULT})
REL_OP      ({MORE_THAN}|{LESS_THAN}|{EQUAL})
LOGIC_OP    ({AND}|{OR})

%%

{SPACE}         { INDENT++; };
{NEWL}          {
                    if (INDENT > DEDENT) print_token("INDENT");  
                    if (INDENT < DEDENT) print_token("DEDENT");   
                    DEDENT = INDENT;
                    line++;
                }
{MULTISTRING}   print_token("MULTISTRING");
{STRING}        print_token("STRING");
{HEX}           print_token("HEX");
{ID}            print_token("ID");
{INTEGER}       print_token("INTEGER");
{COMPLEX}       print_token("COMPLEX");
{REAL}          print_token("REAL");
{IF}            print_token("IF");
{ELSE}          print_token("ELSE");
{LAMBDA}        print_token("LAMBDA");
{FOR}           print_token("FOR");
{PASS}          print_token("PASS");
{COLON}         print_token("COLON");
{LPAREN}        print_token("LPAREN");
{RPAREN}        print_token("RPAREN");
{ARITH_OP}      print_token("ARITH_OP");
{REL_OP}        print_token("REL_OP");
{LOGIC_OP}      print_token("LOGIC_OP");
{NOT}           print_token("NOT");
{ASSIGN}        print_token("ASSIGN");
.               printf("Line %d: Invalid token ('%s').\n", yylineno, yytext);

%%

static void print_token(const char *token)
{
    printf("Line %d: Found token %s (lexeme: '%s').\n", yylineno, token, yytext);
}

int main(void)
{
    yylex();
}
```

One of the problems is the use of `/` in the rules.  In Lex and Flex, IIRC, that introduces trailing context.  It was not remotely clear to me what it was intended to do in the rules where it was used.  There was at least one `ZERO}` where you needed `{ZERO}`.  You seemed to be trying to use `{.}+` as a synonym for `[.]+` or maybe `.+` (and I generally changed it to `[^"]+` or `[^']+` anyway.

The rule for COMMENT still contains a slash.  It appears that a hash marks the end of a comment (but is not part of a comment), not the start of a comment; that is more than a little unusual (I think it is actually unusable) as a comment convention.

And as to how I made this work, I did it one bit at a time.

I moved the bits that caused compilation errors out of the way — into comments.  When I'd got something that compiled, I tested it (on its own source code).  Then I collected one of the broken rules, kept a record so I knew what the original was, and modified it so it made some sense to me.  Rinse, repeat, one step at a time.  I used a VCS (actually, `git`) as I was going, so I knew I could recover a 'working' version if I made a drastic mistake.  You do use a VCS, don't you?

Comment: Hey Jonathan, I used / in the rules , for example : x/y to say "an x only if followed by y". I don't know if I used it correctly ! 
for the {.} : I meant by saying , " any character but new line", is it the correct way to type it ?
I don't know what VCS is, i'll google that !!

Comment: Fair enough if the slashes were there on purpose, but they seemed to be a major component of the trouble.  Generally, you should avoid using trailing context; most rules in most languages get by without needing them.  I don't recall needing to use them, and would not expect to do so for what I think you're doing. The `{.}+` notation is wrong; you need `[.]+` instead.

Comment: VCS is Version Control System, such as git, Mercurial, Subversion, Bazaar, RCS, CVS, SCCS, Perforce, ClearCase, and so on.

Comment: how do i count spaces at the beggining of the line ?? is that the correct way : ((^{SPACE})|({SPACE}/(^{SPACE}*)))

Comment: Forget this `/` business; it complicates your life unnecessarily.  You use it only in emergency; counting spaces at the start of a line is not an emergency. `^{SPACE}*` is sufficient; it matches zero or more spaces at the start of the line. You don't have to tell about what follows; anything that isn't a space stops the rule, including a newline. Your trailing context doesn't make sense to me; you can't have a space followed by a space at the start of the line; if you're looking for a negated character class, that isn't how you write it (`[^ ]` would do; I dunno about using `{SPACE}` in that).

Comment: Ok got it, I'm new to this so i'll take the pro advices !! :).
About the INTEGER rule , it's supposed to be ({SIGN}?{NUM}+)  right ??

Comment: That's about right, yes.  Whether you need the parentheses around it is open to discussion.  I'd use the parentheses when necessary, but avoid them when not.  Simply defining INTEGER, they're probably not necessary.  When defining REAL, then you might add parentheses around INTEGER in that rule.

Comment: will +0-1-0001+002 be analyzed as 4 times integer ??

Comment: What happened when you tried it? (Yes.) The system would like to move this to chat; we can't because you don't have enough rep.  But this conversation needs to stop. Get the simple stuff working.  Then move onto the more complex. If you run into a roadblock, ask a new question with the minimum code — an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)). Clean out as much clutter as you can, and ask about what's left.